# ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'scrapy' for Windows 7

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm running Python 3.6 on Windows 7 64 bit, installed scrappy 1.4 via miniconda.  I'm trying to import scrapy to run the tutorial, but getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\Python stuff\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\quotes_spider.py", line 1, in 
    import scrapy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Did you install "scrappy" (2 R's) or "scrapy"?

Comment: "scrapy"  (1P)  mistyped here, but not on install

Comment: You can perhaps read https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html and check with `conda list` if scrapy was properly installed

Comment: Yes, I see scrapy in installed correctly.  It is in a different directory than my python scripts.  Do I need to have the package in the same directory or sub directory?

Comment: No you don't need to have the package in the same directory. If you [created an environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment) in conda, activated it, [installed scrapy in it](https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-a-package) (using `conda-forge` channel, i.e. `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`), and `import scrapy` does not work, then I don't know what the issue is

Comment: yes, did that.  unfortunately same problem.  Thanks for your help trying to fix